# Test failing with " testRegistration.forEach is not a function "

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am getting following error in cypress for the below test.

*The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

> testRegistration.forEach is not a function*

```
export const testRegistration = ({firstName, lastName, email, password, confirmPassword}) ={

  cy.get('input[name="firstName"]').type(firstName)

  cy.get('input[name="lastName"]').type(lastName)
  
  cy.get('input[name="email"]').type(email)
 

  cy.get('input[name="password"]').type(password)

  cy.get('input[name="confirmPassword"]').type(confirmPassword)

  return cy.contains('button', 'Register').click()

}
```

I am trying to shorten the above code with foreach ,

```
export const testRegistration = ({firstName, lastName, email, password, confirmPassword}) => {
      
  return cy.contains('button', 'Register').click()
        
}

testRegistration.forEach(function (argument, index) {

  cy.get(`input[name= "${argument}"]`).type(argument);

});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to `.forEach()` on the incoming parameter properties

```js
export const testRegistration = (options, buttonText) => {
      
  Object.keys(options).forEach(key => {
    cy.get(`input[name="${key}"]`).type(options[key])
  })
  return cy.contains('button', buttonText).click()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is working. while testing with this answer,first i got syntax error .
moved ')' at the end to before return, then it is working

Comment: Well done, I miss-placed that bracket.

Comment: I need to pass  button value dynamically for all tests like button text will change according to  register , login => " return cy.contains('button', 'Register').click() " , Can I pass it with options?

Comment: It's probably better to pass it as a second parameter so it doesn't get mixed up with the type commands.